# API gateway body mapping move?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Did the body mapping section move in AWS' API Gateway?

Solved: new user error, see below.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266271/where-does-one-configure-mapping-templates-in-aws-api-gateway-or-lambda) about Body mapping and I am trying to connect with a service that has a health check like feature that uses application/x-www-form-urlencoded that I cannot seem to pass through the API gateway. The solution in the thread looks like it it would resolve my issue but the section I see on their post is non existent for me. Does anyone know if there is something I can do to activate it?

I have tried adding an ANY method under a resource and seeing if allowing CORS opens anything with no luck, all the AWS docs I find point me to the same spot as well.

[my API gateway integration options](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/one-for-all-voice/APIgateway.png)

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329958/how-to-pass-a-querystring-or-route-parameter-to-aws-lambda-from-amazon-api-gatew) states that mapping is no longer needed, the detail I missed was that I thought I had redeployed the API after enabling proxy integration, saving a lambda function and saving an API deployment do very different things. I'll leave my mistake on the internet as this would have helped me 2 days ago :)